# How to update the amount of products in the basket without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I work with React & Redux and try to implement a basket(It's a test project). I get an array with products that looks like this:

```
 products: [
        {
            name: "Product one",
            count: 1,
            price: 100,
        },
        {
            name: "Product two",
            count: 1,
            price: 200,
        },
    ]
```

In the basket I map it. There is an opportunity to increase the quantity of products and displays the total amount depending on how many units of goods you have chosen.
For example, 2 units of products that cost 100, on the side there will be a total of 200.
But since I work with LocalStorage, the amount will change only after I refresh the page.
How can I fix this error?
If more detailed information is needed, please inform.

Bucket

```
            <div className="bucket">
                    {this.props.products.map((value,index)=>{
                        return(
                            <div className="product">
                                <h3>{value.price}</h3>
                                <div className="count">
                                    <input type="number" value={value.count} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
                                    <button onClick={()=>this.props.increase(value,this.props.products)}>+</button>
                                </div>
                                <h3>{value.price*value.count}</h3>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        products: state.Stack.products,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        handleChange: (value)=>dispatch(handleChange(value)),
        increase: (product,products)=>dispatch(increase(product,products)),
    }
}
```

Action

```
export function increase(product,products){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        products.map((value)=>{
            if(value == product){
                value.count ++;
            }
        })
        dispatch(newProducts(products));
    }
}



export function newProducts(products){
    return{
        type: NEW_PRODUCTS,
        products
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
const initialState ={
 products: [
        {
            name: "Product one",
            count: 1,
            price: 100,
        },
        {
            name: "Product two",
            count: 1,
            price: 200,
        },
    ]
}

export default function (state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case HANDLE_CHANGE:
            return{
                ...state, value: action.value.target.value
            }
        case NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state, products: action.products
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you storing the cart as a normal state in React/Redux or only using LocalStorage? It should be updated every time the state changes

Comment: Yes, in reducer i have an array products. I updated description you can check. I rewrite an array products when change count of product in bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create a new product I think it would be better if you append it to the existing array of products

instead of having it like

```
        case NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state, products: action.products
            }
```

how about you try

```
        case NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state, products: [...state.products, action.products]
            }
```

and if the `action.products` is an array containing more than one products, make sure to use the spread operator to make sure you are pushing each product individually

in that case the line `products: [...state.products, action.products]`
will change to `products: [...state.products, ...action.products]`

Kindly let me know if this answers your question.